# Delete one autoshape in a range - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, shapes

[image]

This is what i try to do. When i click on one button, the autoshape above is copied in the A8:F12 rectangle.

The code for the 1st button(recorded macro):

```
Sub addTextbox1()
    Range("A2:C3").Select
    Range("C2").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Range("B9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

My problem is i want to make a button which can erase the autoshape in the A8:F12 range. I found this which delete all autoshapes in the worksheet:

```
Sub DeleteShapes()
Dim Shp As Shape
For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
Shp.Delete
Next Shp
End Sub
```

or delete an autoshape by its name (don't work in my case, new autoshapes are generated so i don't know their name)

I know it's fast to click on the shape and press 'delete' but by curiosity i wanted to know if it's possible to do it in VBA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way below is to test whether the top left cell of the shape lies in your deletion range:

```
Sub DeleteShapes()
Dim Shp As Shape
    For Each Shp In ActiveSheet.Shapes
         If Not Application.Intersect(Shp.TopLeftCell, ActiveSheet.Range("A8:F12")) Is Nothing Then Shp.Delete
    Next Shp
End Sub
```